# how to do Unit testing in flutter,Mockito when we make a post request using Dio package?

Tags: java, android, flutter, unit-testing, testing

**Dio request for login authentication**

```
 Future<String?> authentication(String mobileNumber, String password, Dio dio) async {
    dynamic data = {
      "username": mobileNumber,
      "password": password,
      "grant_type": "password",
      "client_id": "client_id"
    };

    try {
      final response = await _dio.post(baseurl,
          data: data,
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          })); //'Authorization': 'Bearer $token
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        accessToken = response.data["access_token"];
        refreshToken = response.data["refresh_token"];
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Successfully Logged in");
        return accessToken;
      }
    }on DioError catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Something went wrong");
      return e.toString();
  }
  return accessToken;
  }
```

**Unit testing **

```
 MockDio mockDio = MockDio();

 test("if authentication successfull token will return  ", () async {
 

when(mockDio.post(Apiservices().baseurl)).thenAnswer((_)async =>*need return a response????*
  );

      expect(await service.authentication("username", "password", mockDio),
          isA<String>());
    });
```

I need to check the login auth testing using dio and mockito packages.
It will return a token.
I am not able to do the mocking.

Please give a details example of this.
or give me some reference

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

> ```
>  test(
>     'Given: Fake login request with username and password,'
>     'When: Mock login API,'
>     'Then: Successful response from mock api', () async {
>   // arrange
>   when(
>       mockDio.post(
>        Apiservices().baseurl
>     ),
>   ).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async {
>     return Response(jsonEncode(loginSuccessResponse), 200); //this will create  a response for your api request
>   });
>
>   // act, this will return a fake api response, we created above
>   final resp = await _networkCallMock.post(
>    Apiservices().baseurl
>   );
>
>   // assert, actualResponse we mocked to get from api call, have a actual  
>   // response as expectedResponse, and compare it.
>   final actualResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body));
>   final expectedResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(loginSuccessResponse);
>   expect(
>     actualResponse,
>     expectedResponse,
>   );
> });
> ```